# Last modified by field is not updating in sharepoint office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, library

We have a SharePoint 365 site and we are having an issue with last modified by field throughout the website.

whenever we update any list item or document library, last modified by field is not updating, it will display the created username under last modified by field and its happening only for this filed. last modified date is working fine.

**Example:**

1. loggedin with USER1 and created a List and an item within. created by the user is USER1
2. loggedin with USER2 and updated the existing record and the record updated successfully, now created by the user is USER1 and last modified by the user is still USER1(should be USER2) and this is happening throughout the site.

We really have no idea from when it's happening until the end user reports this and we don't know where to check and how to fix this issue.

Any help on this really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if the the schema of `Modified By` matches below default schema for `Modified by` field?

```
<Field ID="{d31655d1-1d5b-4511-95a1-7a09e9b75bf2}" ColName="tp_Editor" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="User" List="UserInfo" Name="Editor" DisplayName="Modified By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Editor" FromBaseType="TRUE"/>
```

Below is the PowerShell to get the field Schema:

EDIT:

Adding CSOM Code as it is office 365.

```
$SiteURL = "[URL]"

Write-Host "Loading CSOM libraries" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Write-Host "Lib. successfully loaded !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green 


$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition


$User = Read-Host -Prompt "username"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString


Write-Host "Trying to reach $SiteURL // Handling ClientContext..." -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $password) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials 
$context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
try
{
  $context.ExecuteQuery()
  Write-Host "Connected !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
}
catch
{
  Write-Host "Impossible to reach $SiteURL : bad password ?" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
  return
}


$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tender List");
$fields = $list.Fields;
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
$context.Load($list)
$context.Load($fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$fields | select SchemaXML  |  Export-Csv -path "d:\blabla.csv";
```

[Reference link CSOM and PowerShell](https://www.itunity.com/article/connecting-spo-csom-api-powershell-1038)

Comment: hi, Thanks for the quick response, but how can i check schema for Modified By field? i am new to sharepoint and have no idea how to check this. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the above code won't help as it is for the server object model.

Comment: yeah, i was wondering how to execute this code, since its office365 as of my knowledge i don't think we can do that, any other solutions?

Comment: Sorry for missing that portion. Added the code.